# Говядина и говеть: этимологическое родство

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли "говядина" и "говеть" однокоренными словами?

Comment: Я не филолог, но как Вам такой вариант: корова - животное травоядное, ест траву, можно сказать постится, т.е. говеет. Такая связь не прослеживается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, эти слова не являются однокоренными, так как произошли от разных корней и имеют разную историю.

Не буду приводить этимологию из Фасмера, а сразу перейду к праславянским реконструкциям, потому что оба слова (*говядина* и *говеть*) исконно славянские.

Итак, слово **говęдо* 'крупный рогатый скот; бык'. К нему прибавляется суф. *-ин(а)*, получается **говęдина* 'относящаяся к крупному рогатому скоту', которому соответствует и современное русское *говядина*. Само слово **говęдо* членится на основу **гов- (*гу-)* и суф. *-ęд(о)*. А вот праславянская основа **гов- (*гу-)*, очевидно, продолжает индоевропейскую **gwow-s (*gwōw-s)* 'крупный рогатый скот' и имеет соответствия в др.-инд. *gau-*, авест. *gāu-*, арм. *kov*, лтш. *guovs*, лат. *bōs, bovis* и т. д.

Теперь перейдем к слову *говеть*. Оно соответствует праславянскому **говēти*, продолжающему и.-е. **ghowē-* 'обращать внимание, замечать'.

Видно, что даже и.-е. основы **неодинаковы**, равно как и праславянские. Но если и это выглядит неубедительным, попробуйте пойти от обратного — обосновать семантическую связь между *говядиной* и *говеть*...

*Использованы данные "Этимологического словаря современного русского языка" А. К. Шапошникова.*

Comment: ... от обратного не пойду. Ваш новый ответ доставил мне большое удовольствие. Шапошников выглядит очень многообещающе. Спасибо за ваше время.

Answer (score 0):

Разного смысла, но с одинаковыми корнями.

*Говядина* от Говяда (по ЦСС РЯ), санкр. — го, т.е. бык. Рогатый скот, употребляемый в пищу, быки, коровы, овцы.

Говение, *говеть* = благоговеть, тоже из санкр. яз. — го, т.е. речь в духовном смысле, вторая часть значит жертвоприношение. Однако, по другим источникам — от праславянского корня, от которого в числе прочего произошло ст.-славянское говѣти (εὑλαβεῖσθαι «religiose vereri»).

Comment: ЦСС РЯ, Полный церковно-славянский словарь русского языка. Составитель Г.Дьяченко. http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/index.htm

Comment: В интересующем нас срезе Дьяченко был магистром богословия, писателем, а уж потом стал настоятелем храма.